# Intuitive reasoning behind $P(A|B)P(B)=P(A,B)$

Tags: probability, independence

I understand that by Baye's rule that both sides are equal. However, I can't get my head around why $$P(A|B)P(B)=P(A,B)$$ i.e. why does multiplying by what we are conditioning on give $P(A,B)$ (i.e.both of the events occurring)? Would someone be kind enough to provide some sort of elementary example to clear this up?

Comment: Intuitively, $\mathbb{P}(A \mid B)$ is the probability that A occurs given B occurs. But this is assuming that $B$ has occurred. 'Intuitively' the probability that both A and B occur is $\mathbb{P}(B) \mathbb{P}(A  \mid B)$ i,e: the probability that A  occurs given B occurs multiplied by the probability that B actually does occur. I presume this isn't really the intuition you're looking for, but it might help a little.

Comment: This is not Bayes' Rule; it's a *definition*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\def\P{\operatorname{\mathsf P}}$The intuition is that the probability for $A,B$ to jointly occur is *proportional* to the probability for $B$ to occur and the coefficient of proportionality is some number in $[0;1]$.   It cannot be less than zero, because the joint probability cannot be less than zero.   It cannot be more than $1$ because the joint probability cannot be more than the probability for $B$ .

It should also have *some* relation to the event $A$.   Then let us call this the coefficient of proportionality for $A$ given $B$, denoted by $C_{A\mid B}$.   Defined such that: $$\P(A\cap B) = C_{A\mid B}\P(B)$$

By symmetry there should likewise be a coefficient of proportionality for the complement of $A$ when given $B$; because why not.$$\P(A^\complement\cap B)= C_{A^\complement \mid B}\P(B)$$

Then $C_{A\mid B}\P(B)+C_{A^\complement \mid B}\P(B)= \P(A\cap B)+\P(A^\complement\cap B)$, so therefore $C_{A\mid B}+C_{A^\complement\mid B}=1$.

This suggests these coefficients have properties of probability measures.   Further investigation shall reveal that, indeed they do.   Let us then call them conditional probability measures.

That is *more or less* why we define $\P(A\mid B)$ to be such that: $$\P(A\cap B)=\P(A\mid B)\P(B)$$.

Comment: Thank you for you detailed answer!

Answer (score 2):

When we are faced with only a finite number of outcomes in a universe $U$, one way of calculating the probability of an event $A$ is to calculate
$$\text{probability of } A= \frac{\text{outcomes in }A}{\text{total outcomes }}.$$

Now suppose that we take this equation, and we focus only on the outcomes given that $B$ is true, i.e., we temporarily think of the outcomes in $B$ as being the only thing that exists in our universe.

$$\text{probability of } A \text{ given } B= \frac{\text{outcomes in }A \text{ given } B}{\text{total outcomes }\text{ given } B} = $$

Translating this to the conditional notation we are familiar with:

$$P(A|B) = \frac{|A \cap B|}{|B|} = \frac{|A \cap B|}{|U|}\frac{|U|}{|B|} = \frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}$$

or
$$P(A|B)P(B) = P(A\cap B).$$

EDIT: Of course, this doesn't show anything in terms of the case of an infinite number of outcomes, but I think it serves as a good motivating explanation of why we would define the conditional probability in such a way.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Makes sense now

Answer (score 0):

One can consider a multiple step experiment. Say there are 3 white and 7 black balls in a box. If two balls are taken randomly, the probability of taking first white and second black is:

$P(W\cap B)=P(W)\cdot P(B|W).$

Let's look at the probability tree diagram:
[image]

Note that the probability of taking B the second time depends on the probability of taking W the first time (therefore they are called dependent events).